# Sum of binomial coefficients and powers

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

The following identity is true for $n\geq1$:

$$
n!=\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{n-k} {n\choose k} k^{n}
$$

You can obtain it from the equation in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1149373/commutative-ring-product-of-elements-in-terms-of-sum-of-powers-of-sums) by setting the variables equal to 1.

I was wondering if anyone could come up with an elementary proof, maybe a counting argument? (I've found this rather tricky)

Comment: Turns out this is a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465172/show-this-equality-the-factorial-as-an-alternate-sum-with-binomial-coefficients), sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of proofs [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465172/show-this-equality-the-factorial-as-an-alternate-sum-with-binomial-coefficients).

It really looks like inclusion-exclusion here, so I would go for the accepted answer in the post I linked to (the [other one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Definition), however, also appeals to inclusion-exclusion), but at the moment I do not understand fully the argument there. Will try and come back later.

Comment: Nice find. I honestly did do some searching.

Comment: Thanks. It seems the Stirling argument is the right one, as it provides your counting argument as well.